# Is it possible to auto-fill with zeroes when subtracting output of two calls to `summary` on factors?

Tags: r

Suppose I want to compare two lists of equal size using the frequency of values in each list.

Consider the following script.

```
foo = c(24,24,24,3,10,2)
bar =  c(24,24,10,3,3,2)

summary(as.factor(foo))
summary(as.factor(bar))


summary(as.factor(foo)) -  summary(as.factor(bar))
```

As long as the set of discrete values in `foo` and `bar` are identical, this works reasonably well. Here is some output:

```
 2  3 10 24 
 1  1  1  3 

 2  3 10 24 
 1  2  1  2 

 2  3 10 24 
 0 -1  0  1
```

However, if there is some value in `bar` which is not in `foo`, then, we get the undesirable default behavior of recycling the shorter vector and also a mismatch of counts. Consider the case where

```
bar =  c(24,24,11,3,10,2)
```

Then, our output looks like this, along with a warning message.

```
 2  3 10 24 
 1  1  1  3 

 2  3 10 11 24 
 1  1  1  1  2 

 2  3 10 11 24 
 0  0  0  2 -1 
Warning message:
In summary(as.factor(foo)) - summary(as.factor(bar)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The desired output is:

```
 2  3 10 11 24 
 0  0  0  -1 1
```

In particular, note that a `0` has been filled for the missing `11` in `foo`, and that the value for `24` is `3 - 2 = 1` .

How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the same levels when turning `foo` and `bar` into factors.

```
> foo2 = factor(foo, levels=sort(union(foo, bar)))
> bar2 = factor(bar, levels=sort(union(foo, bar)))
> summary(foo2) - summary(bar2)
 2  3 10 11 24 
 0  0  0 -1  1
```

Answer (score -1):

i have no idea why you want to do this:

```
> summary(factor(foo, levels=union(foo,bar))) -  summary(factor(bar, levels=union(foo,bar)))
24  3 10  2 11 
 1  0  0  0 -1
```